# Запустить Intent ACTION_VIEW минуя intent-filter

Tags: android, intent-filter

Всем привет. Есть `intent-filter`

```
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPattern="/feed/.*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPattern="/feed/.*"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPattern="/feed/.*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPattern="/feed/.*"
                android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Он ловит диплинки, все замечательно, но требуется запускать любые ссылки изнутри приложения минуя intent-filter. Вот этот стандартный код:

```
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
context.startActivity(browserIntent)
```

Вызывает окно выбора приложения но в этом списке есть мое приложение, из которого этот интент запущен. Как его оттуда убрать?

Comment: Кажется так можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23268821/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к огромному сожалению только такого типа ответы нахожу. Они не работают, даже если я шлю пустой массив интентов в `putExtra` - то чузер открывается с одним МОИМ приложением

Comment: Там ниже ещё есть предложение указать конкретное приложение для обработки интента. Если это работает, то можно собрать у системы список возможных приложений для обработки и отобразить их в своём, не системной диалоге и запускать конкретное приложение таким способом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб странно что не нагуглил я решения с системным чузером.. думал у intent-filter будет атрибут external но не тут то было

Comment: Такие вот дела) Не всё можно через системные компоненты сделать, приходится иногда свои пилить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ладно.. вопрос пусть открыт будет вдруг найдется решение у кого-то